# Make page stay focused on Newly added Div

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an option in my page where in I can add new div on button click.
But when ever I add new div the page scrolls back to top, instead of staying focused on new item.

How can i make page stay focused on newly added div??

Answer (score 1):

You can use .focus().docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As if that button is created using `<a href="#">` tag then whenever you click on it due to href="#" it will automatically go to top of the page.
So you need to give either "ID" of that new appended DIV or "javascript:;".
If you passed ID of the DIV then that DIV focused and if you given "javascript:;" then that page will be there only it will perform the action whatever the action function written on click of it.

OR

If that DIV is loading after some service call then you need to handle it through JS you can use event.stopPropagation() function.

If that button is simple `<button>` element then add an attribute "type" as `<button typr="button">` default type is submit so some times its perform some action if that button is included in some `<form>`

I am assuming the scenario because that Js Fiddle link is not accesible. 
Hope it will helps.